# Open Refine--create new column by looking up values from a pair of columns

Tags: openrefine, grel

I have a table in OpenRefine with columns A, B, and C like this:

`A | B | C | D 
---|---|---|---
 a | 1 | b | 2
 b | 2 |   |
 c | 3 | a | 1
 d | 4 | c | 3`

I want to create a column D by fetching the values from B corresponding to those in C, using A as an index. Hope that makes sense? I'm not having much luck figuring out how to do this in GREL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 'cross' function to look up values across the project. Cross is usually used to look up values in a different OpenRefine project/file, but actually it works the same if you point it back at the same project you are already in.

So - from Col C, you can use "Add new column based on this column" with the GREL:

```
cell.cross("Your project name","Col A")
```

You'll get back an array of 'rows' - and if the same value appears in Column A multiple times you could get multiple rows.

To extract a value from the array you can use something like:

```
forEach(cell.cross("Your project name","Col A"),r,r.cells["Col B"].value).join("|")
```

The final 'join' is necessary to convert the array into a string which is required to be able to store the result (arrays can't be stored directly)

Comment: Thanks @owen-stephens, this is just what I needed. One minor edit: it should be `cross(cells,"Your project name","Col A")`. I used the second formula you gave, and cleaned up the results with `substring(value,0,37)`, because my 37-character result was repeated many times.

Comment: Great. Generally I’d recommend using .unique() to remove duplicates from an array- you can insert it before the join() statement. But if it works it works :)

Comment: @OwenStephens Very smart solution !

Comment: Thanks both - updated answer to include the missing 'cell' reference noted by @WillHanley